# Minimum losses to eliminate you from top 2 in round robin

Tags: combinatorics

In a round robin tournament with $n\geq 10$ teams, each match ends in either a win or loss. What is the minimum number of losses to ensure that a team is out of contention of top 2 spots?

**Clarification:** *If two teams score the same, it's good enough because they aren't eliminated.*

**My attempt:** assign them ranks 1 to $n$. There are a total of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ matches and hence as many wins. So, the rank 1 needs to have atleast $\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor$ wins. Keeping them out of the picture, the rank 2 will have atleast $\left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{2}\right\rfloor$ wins. So, if you lose atleast $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}+1\right\rfloor$ matches then you're out.

Is the above attempt correct? It'll be very helpful if someone can confirm.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: First place needs at least $\lceil \frac {n-1}2 \rceil$ because it needs to be at least an average result.  To get the worst record to tie for second you want the winner to win all its games.  The other $n-1$ teams play a tournament for second and any team that has worse than an average record cannot win that.

Answer (score 0):

If draws are equal to victory you are wrong because in four players first can win 3 games and all others win just one and you still win although you lost 3 games ($\frac{4}{2}$ + 1).

If draws are not good enough, 2 losses will eliminate you (again, I'm talking about 4 players).

*the draws are talking about ranking and not about a single game

Your mistake is that you assumed first place will win the least amount of games possible while you prefer he wins as much as possible because your wins are limited and the opponent's wins are not.

In more than 9 players/teams, the solution may be correct and may not, but either way, the way you got there is wrong. you should assume first gets n-1 wins, and that leaves n(n-2)/2 wins.

- If draws are good enough, there are $(\frac{n(n-2)}{2})$ wins left and you need ceiling$(\frac{n(n-2)}{2(n-1)})$ wins and therefore floor(n - $\frac{n^{2}-2n}{2n-2}$) will  eliminate you
- If not, you need floor($\frac{n^{2}-2n}{2n-2}$) + 1 to win and therefore you need ceiling($n + 1 -\frac{n^{2}-2n}{2n-2}$) to eliminate you

Comment: Two losses ISN'T enough to eliminate us if the eventual winner loses a couple of games, though. Considering the question is "What is the minimum number of losses to **ensure** that a team is out of contention of top 2 spots?", 2 is too low an answer. Heck, in any decently sized real-life tournament, only 2 losses would probably put you in a considerable lead. Also, there are no draws.

Comment: in four players it is, assuming draws aren't good enough.

Comment: i am sorry ... edited it to be atleast 10 teams

Comment: are draws good enough or not?

Comment: yes they are, they don't actually ensure your elimination

Comment: please clarify that in the question